# Can't install Pipenv on Windows

Tags: python, django, pip, pipenv

I'm building the backend of an app in Python and I wanted to use Django. The problem is, I installed pipenv with pip3 the first time and it run smoothly, now if I try to install with pip only it tells me:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pipenv in c:\users\marco\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (2023.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv>=20.24.2 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (20.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\users\marco\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pipenv) (2024.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=67 in c:\users\marco\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pipenv) (69.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs<5,>=3.9.1 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv>=20.24.2->pipenv) (4.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.7 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv>=20.24.2->pipenv) (0.3.8)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.12.2 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv>=20.24.2->pipenv) (3.13.3)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.3; however, version 24.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

but if I try to run pipenv --version PowerShell tells me:

```
pipenv : Termine 'pipenv' non riconosciuto come nome di cmdlet, funzione, programma eseguibile o file script.
Controllare l'ortografia del nome o verificare che il percorso sia incluso e corretto, quindi riprovare.
In riga:1 car:1
+ pipenv
+ ~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pipenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

(which by the way is the "not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" error in Italian), meaning that it seems uninstalled.
What should I do? I am new to Python.
I know this is probably a beginner error.
Should I uninstall it? But how can I do it?

If somebody can help me please thank you.

Comment: I think this question belongs to [https://superuser.com](https://superuser.com)